Adblock custom filter block element on main domain but not subdomains on Brave Android
I'm trying to block recommended videos on YouTube main page only (m.youtube.com) excluding channels (i.e. links like m.youtube.com/@*, for example, m.youtube.com/@deathgrippin.
So far, I've been only able to block all video blocks everywhere:
m.youtube.com##.rich-grid-renderer-contents

Where .rich-grid-renderer-contents is the lowest level div accessible.
The following works in mobile Firefox with uBlock Origin but not in Brave:
m.youtube.com##.rich-grid-renderer-contents:not(span:matches-path("/@"))

Adding exception filters doesn't work:
@@youtube.com/@

Matching domain via Regex doesn't work either:
/^youtube\.com(?!\/@)/##.rich-grid-renderer-contents

Need some help!

As you noticed, Firefox with uBlock Origin will be your best combination of tools.  You get the most power and flexibility.
